# How to implement isValid connection for using with Oracle driver classes12?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, connection

I need implement

```
boolean isValid(int timeout)
```

like in jdk6 for java.sql.Connection. But should use Oracle thin driver classes12. 
It is clear that I can run small query, but what about timeout? Should I create separate thread for it?
Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use the Oracle JDBC Driver for Java 6?

Comment: I cannot select. it doesn't depend from me. If I can - I never ask this question.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with. Why can't you use it? Just thinking you can modify the Java 1.2 Oracle JDBC driver so you can use it under Java 6 is foolish when you can just obtain the Java 6 driver.

Comment: Also I am interested in this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For OJDB7:

*isValid(int timeout)* - is a wrapper on the method pingDatabase(int i)
*pingDatabase()* - make query "SELECT 'x' FROM DUAL".
*pingDatabase(int i)* - make the same query in separate thread.

The answer - yes, you have to make a small request in a separate thread.

```
try {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                result = ...make query and verify result
            } catch(Throwable throwable) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
    thread.join(timeout);
    return result;
catch(InterruptedException interruptedexception) {
    return false;
}
```